# Laravel app doesn't send email notifications to gmail account

Tags: laravel

I just wanna enquire something

I have a school application done in laravel whereby when a user is added to the system it will send a notification email informing the user about his registration is success, passwords and stuff.

The problem now when I try to register a user who has a gmail account (vusumzi@gmail.com) as an email, it doesn't send the notification mail, but when I use other email account (vusumzi@yeboict.co.za) it does work fine.

what could be the problem?... my website is on production not dev

Comment: Have you checked gmail's spam folder?

Comment: @Djave.. Oh thanks... why is it going to spam? how can I make it go to inbox?

Comment: I'd be lying if I said I knew how. I think it can be quite complex, but `SPF records` and `DKIM records` would be worth a Google.